# How to create table on MYSQL using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi everyone I am trying to create table and add items on MYSQL but I always get this error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near at line 6"

Can't track the specific problem any idea please? Here's my code

```
import mysql.connector

class GpdealsSpiderPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.create_connection()
    self.create_table()

def create_connection(self):
    self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host = 'www.host1.com',
        user = 'userhost',
        password = 'samplepassword',
        database = 'databasesample'
    )
    self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

def create_table(self):
    self.curr.execute("""create table saleitems_hm(
                    hm_title text,
                    hm_regular_price text,
                    hm_sale_price text,
                    hm_photo_url text,
                    hm_description_url,
                    )""")
```

Please Help me Thank you

Comment: I just hope, that are not your right credentials.

Comment: Thank you @NoorJafri :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your create table query needs **datatype**

Comment: I am super stupid, I am just thinking too much, just overlooked at my code thank you @arun